# Load default project from GPKG

Tags: qgis, geopackage, data-management

One can store QGIS projects in GPKG files. This is handy if one wants to keep data and representation tightly together.

Is there a way to configure or define a project, which is stored in a GPKG, so that QGIS will automatically load it if the GPKG is opened or dropped to the QGIS window? E. g. by naming project and file in a special way or via a specific project flag?

Comment: Since I usually don't save projects to gpkg - how does a project within a gpkg behave natively when you drag&drop it into QGIS?

Comment: QGIS shows it as entry in the list of GPKG contents among layers, with a project icon.

Comment: And you don't want to have to click the project icon, but have the project open automatically. Mhmm, I'll play around a bit, may something comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible. A GeoPackage containing a QGIS project will always trigger the GUI window for selecting sublayers, no matter the user configuration:

> Settings -> Options -> Data Sources -> Prompt for sublayers when opening

This happens because [the function](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/0562154db97f7b551788c8971e133d182482f67a/src/app/layers/qgsapplayerhandling.cpp#L678) that decides if it is necessary to open the window always returns `SublayerHandling::AskUser` when the GeoPackage contains any "non-layer" items, and a project inside a GeoPackage is considered as a "non-layer" item. `SublayerHandling::AskUser` is the flag that says to open the GUI window.

If you are interested in this feature, you should post a new [feature request issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Feature+Request&projects=&template=15_feature_request.yml) on the QGIS Github

Comment: @bugmenot123 If this does answer your question please accept it, if not, explain why it doesn't thanks. I have multiple answers to your questions pending (this one, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/469859/144074) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470063/144074))